# Silverlight OOB White Screen Of Death: Silverlight Installation required after each reboot

Tags: silverlight

we are getting White Screen Of Death on few user's machine for last few months and a number of users is getting added from last month for the same issue. Earlier we were using the CleanSilverlight from the following site

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2608523.

Now we have the following issue that requires immediate fix:

1. Whenever we apply CleanSilverlight then my OOB starts working fine but it start displaying same white screen after few days without any action (Installation/Uninstallation)
2. Whenever the system reboots then we need to apply CleanSilverlight and install the Silverlight once again on user's machine to work with OOB. It seems rebooting interferes with OOB application.

Both of these issues are very frequent from last one month. I don't know if any update to windows/browser is the root cause for the issue.

One the system is having the following configuration to run OOB:

- OS name and version: Windows 7 32-bit
- Browser name & version: IE 8 & Google Chrome 38.0.2125.111 m
- Silverlight version: 5.1.30514.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Maddy

Comment: Any error logs or anything to help identify the culprit? There's generally something to tell you what's breaking to cause the white screen.

Comment: No, Nothing is there to analyze :(. Its just crashing down. One user added in the list have the following configuration: 

1) OS name and version: Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1

2) Browser name & version: Googles Chrome ver 38.0.21125.111m

3) Silverlight version: – 5.1.30214.0